# py2app: how to include modules that will be loaded by __import__?

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I have a Python application that loads python modules dynamically at run time (using `__import__`). The modules to load are in a package called '`plugins`' (i.e. subfolder called `plugins` with `__init__.py` etc). All works fine running from the python interpreter, and even when compiled to a windows binary using py2exe.

I tried building a OSX app from it, which succeeded, but when running the .app I get an ImportError: '`no module named plugins.xxxx`'.

I am pretty sure I gave the correct options to py2app (`'includes': [...]`, `'packages':['plugins']`, identical to what I do for py2exe), since when I browse the .app content, I see all the plugin modules in a folder `Contents/Resources/lib/python2.5/plugins/`.

So, why can't the app find my modules (must be some path issue)?

**Edit:**

I've found a way to make it work, but it isn't a good solution:
When I printed the paths Python searches for modules (using `print sys.path`), I noticed that the folder `Contents/Resources/lib/python2.5/plugins/` was NOT listed. However, the folder `Contents/Resources/` is, so I moved the `plugins` folder to the `Contents/Resources` folder. Now the plugins are found. But I am still not happy with this ugly, manual hack.

Answer (score 0):

Koo uses the following code.  You'll probably need to do something similar to detect that you're in py2app, and adjust your import accordingly.

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openobject-client-kde/openobject-client-kde/5.0/annotate/head%3A/Koo/Common/Plugins.py

```
def scan( module, directory ):
        pluginImports = __import__(module, globals(), locals())
        # Check if it's being run using py2exe or py2app environment
        frozen = getattr(sys, 'frozen', None)
        if frozen == 'macosx_app' or hasattr(pluginImports, '__loader__'):
                # If it's run using py2exe or py2app environment, all files will be in a single 
                # zip file and we can't use listdir() to find all available plugins.
                zipFiles = pluginImports.__loader__._files
                moduleDir = os.sep.join( module.split('.') )
                files = [zipFiles[file][0] for file in zipFiles.keys() if moduleDir in file]
                files = [file for file in files if '__init__.py' in file]
                for file in files:
                        d = os.path.dirname(file)
                        if d.endswith( moduleDir ):
                                continue
                        newModule = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file))
                        __import__( '%s.%s' % (module, newModule), globals(), locals(), [newModule] )
        else:
                for i in os.listdir(directory):
                        path = os.path.join( directory, i, '__init__.py' )
                        if os.path.isfile( path ):
                                __import__( '%s.%s' % (module, i), globals(), locals(), [i] )
```